# VS2017 Error: The operation could not be completed

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to merge some code from a 3rd party.  I thought I merged the source file ok as well as the .vcxproj files.  To test out, I tried to do a compile of a single source file.  It did a compile and failed with a message (don't remember what atm) and I addressed the error and tried to build that source file again.  What I got was

```
1>Error: The operation could not be completed
```

Yes, not very helpful error message and I'm at a loss.  I tried to delete the object files and tried again, I still get the same message.  It doesn't seem even building anything.  What can I do to get VS2017 to give me more helpful diagnostics?  What could be causing this issue?

Comment: is there anything in the output window

Comment: @KenTucker that message was all that was I the output window. That's why I'm having such a problem with this.going to have to try and cherry pick some changes to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when moving a website from .net 2 to .net 4.6.1 which was hosted on local IIS7.5.  It also showed as Visual Studio throwing all manner of errors upon loading the solution (pointing me at the not very helpful activity log)

All of my assemblies had been recompiled to .Net 4.6.1 and I'd changed the app pool to run .net 4 and integrated, however, VS seemed to think the web site should be loaded or compiled as plain .Net 4.0.  This meant that it couldn't load the .Net 4.6.1 assemblies but didn't register this error just said it couldn't complete the operation.

I amended the web.config to add targetFramework="4.6.1" into the compilation element and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same error which drove me mad for hours. It turned out to be due to some sort of mix-up in the compilation configurations in the solution file, which made reference to configurations that did not exist (because the solution had been copied from another with more projects in it). What appeared to fix it was just going into the configuration manager dialog and then saving.